# Как записать два цикла for для одной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка: `first_list` и `second_list`. Как теперь правильно записать для них циклы `for` чтобы передать результат в функцию `get_result`?

```py
def get_first_list():

    first_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

    return first_list

def get_second_list():

    second_list = [1, 2, 3]

    return second_list

def get_result(ifirst, isecond):

    print(ifirst)

    print(isecond)

def main():

    first_list = get_first_list()
    second_list = get_second_list()

    get_first_list()
    for first in first_list:
        ifirst = first
        get_result(ifirst, isecond)

    get_second_list()
    for i in second_list:
        isecond = i
        get_result(ifirst, isecond)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    first_list = get_first_list()
    second_list = get_second_list()
    for ifirst, isecond in zip(first_list, second_list):
        get_result(ifirst, isecond)
```

или

```
def main():
    any(map(get_result, get_first_list(), get_second_list()))
```

это не одно и то же в общем случае, но в данном примере сработает.